# Web service WHERE / ORDER BY (?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, where-clause

I have a web service that returns the list of all the clients.

I can get the list into a gridview by calling the method get all data like this.

```
    test.RH_WebServiceService ligar = new test.RH_WebService();
    test.baseList[] data = ligar.getAllData();
```

The thing is I wanted to filter it by name (for example) I've been reading online and people have said to me that I can just do it like this:

```
test.baseList[] data = ligar.getAllData().Where(condition);
```

However I can't get it to work. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the actual code? What is `condition`?

Comment: It's `.Where()` not `.WHERE()` (C# is case sensitive) and you need to have `using System.Linq`. Beyond that, "can't get it to work" is hardly enough detail to even begin to diagnose the problem.

Comment: thats what some people gave me after i talked about what i needed, i have no idea what they meant by condition im guessing it's something like test.baseList[] data = ligar.getAllData().WHERE(data.name="john"); something like this. but i tried and i cant get it to work

Comment: thanks craig, i wrote it so fast i didnt even notice i messed up. thanks for noticing

Comment: You still have not provided a description of what is wrong, as @CraigW. suggested. Please do so.

Comment: is the code you posted C#? What kind of file is it in, what kind of project are you building?

Comment: what i don't know how to do is what to put between the () (i did try already a bunch of stuff while i was at school) of the Where since i've never even worked with it and i started to use web-services / c# a little while ago. i wondered if any of you had already used it in a similar way as i need to

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Linq then you can just do:

```
test.baseList[] data = ligar.getAllData().Where(d => d.Name == "John");
```

The d is a random letter given to the object. Name is what i am assuming your property is called. Although i would recommend creating a method in your service that you pass the name in and get back the filtered data. That way you only return data you need which will improve performance. Something like this:

```
test.baseList[] data = ligar.getDataByName("John");
```

Comment: thanks' ill try it tomorrow at school. yeah i thought about that but the webservice was given to me and ill have to filter through name, age, etc so they told me to do this way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help some:

```
test.baseList[] data = ligar.getAllData().Where(f=> f.field == "value").ToArray();
```